# Spring Cloud Gateway Query Predicate OR Condition

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working on Spring Cloud Gateway where I wanted to define a route with **Query** predicate, where this route should be matched when any of the Query Param Values matches.

For example: I'm looking for a scenario where a single Query Predicate can take multiple matching values. Is this possible ?

```
- id: test-api
  uri: http://www.myhost.com
  predicates:
   - Path=/v3/test/
   - Method=POST
   - Query=key,value_1,value_2
```

Spring Cloud documentation only speaks about matching a single value for **Query Predicate** - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi_gateway-request-predicates-factories.html#_query_route_predicate_factory

Answer (score 3):

I have found the way to specify multiple query params matches.

As per the spring documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi_gateway-request-predicates-factories.html#_query_route_predicate_factory

the value of it is a regex string. so it can be done by specifying  values separated by `|` operator

```
- id: test-api
  uri: http://www.myhost.com
  predicates:
   - Path=/v3/test/
   - Method=POST
   - Query=key, value_1|value_2
```

Comment: That would be using a regexp, but still the query seems to be case sensitive, and the regexp for the value could handle that, but too how about the key which is only a string? If the proxied service has case insentivity how to support it?